# front end application user can access the website from specific IP address

Tags: block

front end application ( php / .net / Java ) one user can access the website from specific IP address only, that same user can not access the website from other IP address. How to do this. is this possible?.

Comment: Could you not achieve this by using a firewall to restrict the source IP address of the clients accessing the website. What webserver are you running? Most web servers allow you to create a white list of permitted IP addresses

Comment: can you please tell the steps if any.? we are using Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mod_authz_hosts module in Apache to restrict which IP addresses are allowed to access certain sections of the website. Looking through the documentation for the module, you create a .htaccess file in the directory that you want to restrict access and within the file enter details of the allowed IP addresses. For example

```
Allow from 10.1.2.3
```

Take a look at the documentation on the documentation for the module which is available at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html

Comment: Thank u so much... and one more question

Comment: one php website is there. i want to do like this.

Comment: website users can access this website link from particular IP only. How to do this in linux ?

Comment: @user3563068 If you want to restrict access to the whole website then you could create the .htaccess file in the root directory for the website and then specify "Allow from a.b.c.d" in the .htaccess file, replacing a.b.c.d with whatever IP address you want to permit. If the answer to the original question has fixed your problem, would you be able to accept the answer please?